# Prove that, reflection of vertex of a triangle about angle bisector through other vertex lie on opposite side of triangle.

Tags: geometry, proof-writing, triangles

> $A(1,3)$ and $C({-2\over5},{-2\over5})$ are the vertices of a triangle $ABC$ and equation of angle bisector of $\angle ABC$ is $x+y=2$. Find equation of side $BC$

I tried a lot to solve this question, but was unable to. So I decided to look at the solution.

The solution included a line

> *Reflection of a vertex about angle bisector lie on the opposite side of triangle.*

This line is enough to solve this question.

But *why is that true*. Can anyone provide me a proof for it.

Comment: It’s not true as stated. However, the reflection does lie on the _extension_ of the opposite side. Draw the isosceles triangle created by the reflection.

Comment: Thank you, just realized it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By drawing the reflection of A, we get A'.
[image]
P  is a point on x + y = 2 and is on the opposite side of AC other than B.

$\angle ABP = \angle A'BP$ because B lies on the perpendicular bisector of AC.

Also, $\angle ABP = \angle CBP$ because BP is given as the angle bisector of $\angle ABC$.

Therefore, B is on the extension of CA'.